# matplotlib set all plots linewidth in a figure at once

Tags: matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.plot(2 * range(10))
```

I have a function (basic_axis(ax)) that will set spines linewidth (ax.spines.set_linewidth()), tick length (ax.tick_paras(...), ... but I don't find how to also set all plots linewidth with one value. Is it possible to do it through a function that takes only ax as parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the line-like artists are added to `Axes.lines` so you should be able do to this with

```
def bulk_lw_adjuster(ax, lw=5):
    for ln in ax.lines:
        ln.set_linewidth(lw)
```

Comment: Also `plt.setp(ax.lines, linewidth=5)` if you want a one-liner. (In case the OP hasn't come across `setp` before.)