# matplotlib set plot properties through function

Tags: matplotlib

Some time ago I asked how to set line style through a function taking the plot axes instance as parameter
([matplotlib set all plots linewidth in a figure at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463066/matplotlib-set-all-plots-linewidth-in-a-figure-at-once)).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.plot(2 * range(10))

solution suggested:
def bulk_lw_edjuster(ax, lw = 5)
    for ln in ax.lines:
    ln.set_linewidth(lw)
```

As shown above one suggested to use ax.lines in the function, but  now I would like to know how to set other properties such as marker properties, colors ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information about the setting the properties of Lines2D [here.](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) Marker size and marker color can be set similarly to the line width:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.plot(2 * range(10))

#solution suggested:
def bulk_lw_edjuster(ax, lw = 5, markersize  = 5, markerfacecolor  = 'r'):
    for ln in ax.lines:
        ln.set_linewidth(lw)
        ln.set_markersize(markersize) # set marker size
        ln.set_markerfacecolor(markerfacecolor) # set marker color

# Change the plot properties.        
bulk_lw_edjuster(ax, lw =10, markersize = 10, markerfacecolor = 'm')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what about setting legend items font size?

Comment: @user1850133 Please ask a new question if you have new issues.